# Import excel data to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, import

Import excel data to database in codeigniter with same as shown as in excel sheet.

i have already done coding/programming of importing data from excel to database in codeigniter but there is only one issue is that not import same data as like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save your excel as csv and then set sql into UTF8 encoding. CMIIW

Comment: i have already done coding of importing data from excel to database in codeigniter but there is only one issue is that not import same data as like above image